# Modify TextBox value when Button was clicked in custom control library

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I create one textbox and button in custom control library, the initial text box value is "Welcome" when the button was clicked the textbox text value is modified to "Hi".

Generic.Xaml:

```
    <ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="WpfCustomControlLibrary2.Themes.Class1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary2">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txb" Text="Welcome" Width="50" Height="30" FontSize="15"/>
                            <Button Content="+" Width="35" Height="30" FontSize="15" Click="Button_Click_Add" />
                        </WrapPanel>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Class1.cs:

```
namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary2.Themes
{
    partial class Class1
    {
        private void Button_Click_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //What i do here  
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary2;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <local:CustomControl1 />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Please help to solve this problem, Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking?..txb.Text = 'Hi' does not work for you?

Comment: Are you encountering some error?

Comment: please note i try this in Custom Control Library Generic.xaml

Comment: Any specific reason for doing that? Shouldn't you be going for a user control rather than a custom control

Comment: @Ishan070692 : yeah its a part of my program to do something

Comment: That is what I am asking, the task you are right now trying to do is too trivial for a custom control and this is not how a custom control is build. The thing you should go for is user control

Comment: so no way for do this in custom control

Comment: I have no idea how your class1 is connected to .xaml class coz as far as I know.. Custom controls do not have a xaml class rather than the one for setting the style of controls

Comment: Could you update the code for your class1.cs

Comment: Post full Generic.Xaml and code of your custom control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can`t do it, like you do it.
And you must follow name rules also.

Try it:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary2;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary2">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="Welcome"/>
                            <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Content="+" />
                        </WrapPanel>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TextBox", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Button", Type = typeof(Button))]
public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
    }

    public CustomControl1()
    {
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var button = GetTemplateChild("PART_Button") as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click += Button_Click;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.Text = "HI!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MVK Mark this answer as solution if it helped you